# how to use named parameters in the mentioned scenario?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate. I have a requirement to add a `where` condition dynamically. I send list of strings.
           `select * from employee`.

Now I need to add `where` condition as:
 `select * from employee where name like :somename or name like:othername`

Here `somename` and `othername` are named parameters. Values are set from list of strings.
In this case the list can contain two strings so that for both named params values can be set.

How can I use names for named params?

Right now I am using a list of strings for both named params and to set their values.
 Problem is there are few restrictions to use named params.

**Named param should not contain special chars (-,/ and space). Also named param should not be longer than 30 chars**.

If my list of strings has any name with above special chars or its length is more than 30 chars then exception  is thrown if such a string is used as named param.

How can I use named params for each string in the list?

Comment: Your question is an unreadable wall of text. Try breaking it up so that people will actually want to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Criteria API
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Well select with bunch of "where" should not be a probelm with criteria API.. 
just care about the LIKE %

and check this out, and tell me if you need more detail.
http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

Comment: hi darwly thnx for ur reply. Here as an example i mentioned simple employee query. But actual query is too complex where i cannot use criteria and have to use native sql query.

Comment: hi darwly, thanx for ur reply. The link speaks about criteria. But i have to use native sql. My only question is here which names i have to use as named params? Thanx.

Comment: at the start there is a code, with string buffer that shows you how to build the sql with loads of "where"